# Addition of line of latitude to a coordinate system

Tags: arcgis-desktop, grids-graticules

I need to know how to add a line of latitude to a graticule. I want to add a line of 66 deg. 34 minutes to north pole orthographic graticule. I am using ArcGIS

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Can you add more details of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by creating a second graticule with the following settings:

[image]

I had actually set the Interval Y Axis to 66 degrees and 34 minutes but it added 60 seconds.  The result seems correct.

Similarly, I had set my own origin to 66 degrees and 34 minutes, but it changed it to 33 minutes and 60 seconds.  Again, the results are ok (I changed the colour to red for clarity).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I needed to know. I'm so glad you were able to understand the question. I really don't know how to improve it.